# python creating a moving image matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, scatter-plot

I have an image over-top which I would like to plot 2000 x,y coordinates. I am currently using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_coord = [1, 2, 3 .... 2000]
y_coord = [2000, 1999, 1998, .... 1]

# import image
im = plt.imread(file)
implot = plt.imshow(im)

# create a color spectrum
y = np.arange(0, 2000)

# plot x and y coords
plt.scatter(x=x_coord, y=y_coord, c=y, s=10, marker='1')
```

However it is hard to discern the progression of the coordinates with the given color palette. Is there anyway to make an gif of the plots as they are being plotted as to see the progression?

Comment: It might matter what is in the image. Could you include a sample?

Comment: There are quite a few [animation examples](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#animation) on the matplotlib page. A search [like this](https://www.google.de/search?q=matplotlib+animate+scatter+site:stackoverflow.com) would also show some examples. At the end you can save a `FuncAnimation` as animated gif via `ani.save("my.gif", writer="imagemagick")`.